# How to create a MySQL trigger to update a datetime column if another column value changes?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have in a table a column named "purged_on" it is a date time type. I also have another column named "status" this column can have a value from 0-9

I need to add a trigger that will update the "purge_on" column with a date time value of the updated record value of status changes from anything to 0. but if the record changes from status 0 to anything else then I want to remove the purged_on value for that record.

I never used trigger so I am not sure where to start from or this is even doable or not.

I tried the following but got a syntax error
    CREATE TRIGGER update_purge_date
        AFTER UPDATE
        ON phone_calls FOR EACH ROW
         purged_on = CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN NOW() ELSE NULL END;

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.  Hope this helps.  Replace `content` with your table name.

```
CREATE TRIGGER myPurgedOnTrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON content FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.status = 0 and NEW.status <> OLD.status) THEN
        SET NEW.purged_on = current_timestamp();
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.status != 0 and NEW.status <> OLD.status) THEN
        SET NEW.purged_on = null;
    END IF;
END;
```

NOTE: This is a BEFORE update, not an AFTER update.  This is because you need to do the SET command. If you change it to AFTER then try to create the trigger you will get this error: "Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger".

Comment: You changed your question, updating answer now...  Answer has been updated.  It works for me.  I tested it.

Comment: My question is still the same but I added what I have tried.  Using the code your provided is going me a syntax error still

Comment: Replace `content` with your table's name.  If that doesn't fix it then tell me what the error says.

Comment: I did that but did not work. Do I need to change"NEW" and OLD?

Comment: No.  What's the error say?  Are you dropping the trigger before you try to re-create it?  Do `drop trigger myPurgedOnTrigger;` then run my code.

Comment: I still get a syntax error Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45072/discussion-between-mike-and-gfrobenius)

Comment: @gfrobenius: Did this work for you? I have a similar problem and the trigger I wrote using the same method refuses to do anything. :(

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101028/update-timestamp-only-when-a-non-null-value-is-entered-in-another-field